# AS3 include a dynamic variable into a regexp object

Tags: regex, string, actionscript-3, variables

How can I include a dynamic variable into a regexp object?

```
var pattern:RegExp = new RegExp(/'a '/ + keyword, '/gi');
```

In this case, I'd like the regex to match "a bird", or "A biRD" (if 'bird' is the keyword). However, 'bird' should not match if it is on its own.

Furthermore, I have a follow up question (I hope it's not too much to ask!):
How would I do the exact thing above, but in which the regex only matches if the keyword is NOT preceded by 'a ' (I believe this involves the use of the ^ or the !, but I can't seem to find any clear documentation in any language for my specific request).

In the case of my second question test cases would look like this:

WORKS

```
abird
bird
bbbbirdddd
```

DOESN'T WORK

```
a bird
a birdddd
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Okay. I updated the post to include test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActionScript 3.0 supports lookbehinds and the case-insensitive modifier:

```
/(?<=a\s+)bird/i
```

See here for more information on how to construct a regular expression from a variable: [Using a Variable in an AS3, Regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657179/using-a-variable-in-an-as3-regexp).

For the second part of your question:

```
/(?<!a\s+)bird/i
```

Comment: What if instead of "a ", I wanted a longer phrase? Such as "a blue "?

Comment: The lookbehind takes any regular expressions atom!  So, you can even do this: ``/(?<!a big blue )bird/i``.  (And replace the spaces with ``\s+`` for whitepsace flexibility.)  (I recall hearing that some regex engines only allow fixed-width lookbehinds; in that case you may not be able to use quantifiers within the lookbehind.  Not sure if this is the case with AS3.)

Comment: What if "bird" is a dynamic variable? (Bird is just an example of a keyword)

Comment: never mind. i'm making it a string, then just using the string as one to pass to the regex.

Comment: As shown in the link I provided, you have to build a new RegExp object from a string.  ``var str:String = '(?<!a\s+)' + yourDynamicVariable; var regex:Regexp = new RegExp(str, 'i');``